# Typescript React input onchange unsafe assignment 'any'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I get a linting error from an input element when assigning handleChange to onChange prop of input element, "Unsafe assignment of an `any` value."

My code

```
<input
  type="text"
  defaultValue=""
  size={35}
  id="contactName"
  name="contactName"
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

my typings

```
export interface ContactProps {
  data: {
    message: string
    street: string
    city: string
    state: string
    zip: string
    phone: string
  }
  handleChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
}
```

Comment: Can you share a bit more of your code as the example you provide seems correctly typed

Answer (score 0):

It was correctly typed, it was some issue with linting. I restarted my PC and it's not showing any errors now.